# In how many ways can you subtract edges from the graph of a cube so that there are no isolated vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose you have a graph with 8 vertices where each vertex is connected to three others, making 12 edges (essentially the graph of a cube). In how many ways can you subtract edges from the graph so that all of the vertices are not isolated?

I thought about using matrices and Markov chains but that seemed somewhat difficult and tedious. Then, I thought maybe just brute forcing the problem would give me an answer, but that also seemed pointless, as I thought that I could easily make a mistake. I feel like there is definitely an easier way to approach the problem and would love some help if you can think of it!

Comment: I would just count in a computer program.  Draw the graph and number the edges from $0$ to $11$.  Find the $8$ combinations of $3$ edges that isolate a vertex.  Count from $0$ to $2047$, write the numbers in binary, and see if any of the $8$ combinations have all $0$s.  You could do it in a spreadsheet with copy down, although $2048$ rows is a bit much.

Answer (score 1):

Take two opposite vertices.  Each has 1,2 or 3 neighbours.  For each combination, there is a hexagon made by the other six vertices, some of which are already connected.  Count how many ways you can make sure the rest are connected.